# Got Solution How to store the cookies in login and delete the cookies in logout action

Tags: ios, iphone, cookies, nsurlconnection

```
My Problem is solved
```

I am doing an application that is getting cookies from server side. I want to store the cookies and delete the cookies at logout function but I don't know how to do this.
Based on this cookies my app has to show some additional benefits to the user so I want to save this cookies.
This is login request:

```
- (IBAction)enterButtonAction:(id)sender {
        NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"user[email]=%@&user[password]=%@",userNameTF.text,passWordTF.text];
        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)postData.length];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];


         [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];
        NSURLConnection * connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        if (connection != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Connection Successfull");
            self.responseData = [NSMutableData alloc];
            [connection start];
        }else {
            NSLog(@"Failed");
        }


    }
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.responseData appendData:data];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [self.responseData setLength:0];
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSError * parseError = nil;
    NSMutableDictionary * _jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:kNilOptions error:&parseError];
    NSLog(@"%@",_jsonDictionary);
    NSString * roleString = [_jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"role"];

    if ([roleString isEqualToString:@"user"]) {
        UIStoryboard * storyBD = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UITabBarController * obj = [storyBD instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tab"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
    }
    else {
        [self alertStatus:@"Please Enter 'Correct Email & Password'" :nil];
    }

}
```

//// Solution is this one it is working now very fine there is no need to store or delete the cookies every thing will handle this code

```
NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"user[email]=%@&user[password]=%@",userNameTF.text,passWordTF.text];
        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)postData.length];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setValue:@"myCookie" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Set-cookie"];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];
        NSDictionary *cookieProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          @"http://yourwebsite.com", NSHTTPCookieDomain,
                                          @"\\", NSHTTPCookiePath,
                                          @"myCookie", NSHTTPCookieName,
                                          @"1234", NSHTTPCookieValue,
                                          nil];

        NSHTTPCookie *cookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:cookieProperties];
        NSArray* cookieArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:cookie];
        NSDictionary * headers = [NSHTTPCookie requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies:cookieArray];
        [request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];
        NSURLConnection * connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        if (connection != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Connection Successfull");
            self.responseData = [NSMutableData alloc];
            [connection start];
        }else {
            [sharedAppDelegate dismissGlobalHUD];
            NSLog(@"Failed");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the cookies into NSUserDefaults and clear them from user defaults when user clicks on logout button.

Hope this helps!!